# Images uploading, going to the /media/tmp, but not saving in media/catalog after saving product Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

After uploading image in magento product section, image found in media/tmp but folder after saving product it can't move to media catalog folder. I have 755 permission to media/catalog folder. [image: See image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Finally I found that I badly patched with PATCH_SUPEE-8788 v2 and js/mage/adminhtml/product.js was out of date.